# whats would be the compaction strategy for performing better in Range queries on clustered column

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have Cassandra table

```
CREATE TABLE schema1 (
  key bigint,
  lowerbound bigint,
 upperbound bigint,
 data blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, lowerbound,upperbound)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE ;
```

I want to perform a range query by using CQL

```
Select lowerbound, upperbound from schema1 where key=(some key) and  lowerbound<=123 order by lowerbound desc limit 1 allow filtering;
```

**Any Suggsetion please Regarding the compaction strategy**
Note MY read:write ration is 1:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leveled compaction will mean fewer SSTables are involved for your queries on a key, but requires extra IO. Also, during compaction it uses 10% more disk than data, while for size tiered compaction, you need double. Which is better depends on your setup, queries, etc. Are you experiencing performance problems? If not, and if I could deal with the extra IO, I might choose leveled as it means I don't have to keeps 50+% of headroom in terms of disk space for compaction. But again, there's no "one right way".

Perhaps read this:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/leveled-compaction-in-apache-cassandra

Comment: I have gone through that article. But I was worried over its one comment that Level compaction suits for "High Read/Write Ratio" since in my case i have each read followed by a write. That why i am confused.

Comment: Will it slow down the write?

Comment: It does more disk IO for compaction (remember this is a compaction strategy). Writes would go the usual commit log + memtable route. It will make your disks work harder. If you're on slow spinning rust, it may be an issue depending on how much load you're expecting. If you've got iops headroom, not so much. However, each scenario is different, so I recommend trying both out and looking at the measures above the 95th or 97.5th percentiles.

Comment: by 95%  did you mean headroom.(if I am not headroom is remaining space in the disk)

Comment: By 95th percentile, I mean that you collect metrics but look at the values (e.g. latencies) that are in the top 95%. If you look at straight averages, then the metric is skewed as "normal load" low latencies will be dominant over the higher latencies when the system is under load. Looking at the latencies of the upper percentiles ensures you're considering "bad case" scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Size-tiered compaction is the default, and should be appropriate for most use-cases.  In 2012 DataStax posted an article titled [When To Use Leveled Compaction](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction), in which it specified three (main) conditions for which leveled compaction was a good idea:

1. High Sensitivity to Read Latency (your queries need to meet a latency SLA in the 99th percentile).
2. High Read/Write Ratio
3. Rows Are Frequently Updated

It also identifies three scenarios when leveled compaction is not a good idea:

1. Your Disks Can’t Handle the Compaction I/O
2. Write-heavy Workloads
3. Rows Are Write-Once

Note how none of the six scenarios I mentioned above are specific to range queries.

My question would be "what problem are you trying to fix?"  You mentioned "performing better," but I have found that query performance issues tend to be more tied to data model design.  Switching the compaction strategy isn't going to help much if you're running with an inefficient primary key strategy.  By virtue of the fact that your query requires `ALLOW FILTERING`, I would say that changing compaction strategy isn't going to help much.

The DataStax docs contain a section on [Slicing over partition rows](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use-slice-partition.html), which appears to be somewhat similar to your query.  Give it a look and see if it helps.

Comment: Completely agree -- ALLOW FILTERING would kill performance independently from the compaction stragegy

Comment: Didn't scroll far enough to get to allow filtering...it shouldn't be needed for his query as he's doing an equals on a partition key, and a <= on the first clustering key.

Comment: @ashic thanks for pointing. I have removed this from my code.

Answer (score 0):

When Rows Are Frequently Updated
From datasatx article 
Whether you’re dealing with skinny rows where columns are overwritten frequently (like a “last access” timestamp in a Users column family) or wide rows where new columns are constantly added, when you update a row with size-tired compaction, it will be spread across multiple SSTables. Leveled compaction, on the other hand, keeps the number of SSTables that the row is spread across very low, even with frequent row updates.